# how to use git am and favor ours merge strategy

Tags: git

when using `git am` to apply patches there might be some conflicts. `git am` supports [3 way merge (allow fall back on 3way merging if needed)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am#Documentation/git-am.txt---3way) but does not have a support for [`ours`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies) , such as other `git merge\rebase` operations.

how can `git am` and tell it to favor `ours` changes if conflicts arises?

Comment: Note that the `ours` you linked with is the `-s ours` merge *strategy*, not the `-X ours` merge *eXtended strategy option*. You probably want the strategy *option*, not the strategy. (However, it's true that `git am` doesn't have it—it lacks both the strategy *and* the strategy-option.)

Comment: @torek correct, the link should be point to the -X option. got any idea how to deal with the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  You'll just have to go resolve these yourself.

Consider semi-automating this using `git merge-file`, which *does* have the option.  You'll need to retrieve all three input files (merge base, ours, and theirs).